# To approximate $(1+\frac{R^2}{z^2})^{1/2}$ when $z\gg R$ with a Taylor expansion,what's the difference between using $(1+s)^{1/2}$ or $(1+s^2)^{1/2}$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Consider the expression $$\frac{z}{(z^2+R^2)^{1/2}} =\frac{z}{(z^2(1+\frac{R^2}{z^2}))^{1/2}} =\frac{1}{(1+\frac{R^2}{z^2})^{1/2}}.$$

Let's consider what happens when $z\gg R$.

I'd like to approximate the denominator using a first-order Taylor expansion of $(1+\frac{R^2}{z^2})^{1/2}$.

If we call $s=\frac{R}{z}$, then $z\gg R$ means $\frac{R}{z}\to 0$.

$$f_1(s)=(1+s^2)^{1/2}.$$

And near $s=0$ we can say
$$f_1(s) \approx 1$$

because $f_1'(0) = 0$.

If instead we call $s=\frac{R^2}{z^2}$ then we have

$$f_2(s)=(1+s)^{1/2}.$$

And near $s=0$ we can say

$$f_2(s) \approx 1 -\frac{1}{2}s.$$

When we're solving a problem that involves approximating an expression for $z\gg R$, and we have a term $(1+\frac{R^2}{z^2})^{1/2}$, how do we know which function to use for a Taylor expansion?

**I will add some plots here because I think they are interesting**

Here are $f_1$ and first derivative

[image]

[image]

And here are $f_2$ and first and second derivatives

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to use $(1+s^2)^{1/2}$ you should find the term of order $s^2$. Then your two answers should agree. $R^2$ is $2$nd order in $R$ but $1$st order in $R^2$. Also, I think your second approximation is off by a sign.

Comment: It seems like the two answers do not completely agree when we include the second order term in the expansion of $(1+s^2)^{1/2}$. The expansion of the latter becomes $f(s)\approx 1 - \frac{s^2}{2}$. Note that the other expansion was $f(s)\approx 1 - \frac{s}{2}$.

Comment: From the plots I posted, it makes sense that they don't agree. The second order expansion of $f_2$ curves downward for $s<0$, like a parabola, ie the approximation value decreases. The first order expansion of $f_1$ is just a line, so for $s<0$ the approximation gives us a value larger than 1, ie the approximation value increases.

Comment: My question thus remains: why would we use one approximation over the other?

Comment: Yes you will get $1+\frac{s}{2}$ in the second case but then you want to plug in $s=\frac{R^2}{z^2}$, while with $1+\frac{s^2}{2}$ you will plug in $s=\frac{R}{z}$. In either case your approximation is $1+\frac{R^2}{2z^2}$.